# how to display tamil font in vc++

Tags: visual-c++

I want to display tamil font in mfc dialog . How to achieve it?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=internationalize+mfc+application+tutorial) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee845043(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely clear what you want to do, but `CWnd` has a `SetFont()` method that you can use. You can use that to set the font of the various controls on the dialog. You will probably need to call it for each control on your dialog.

There's some good info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx

Comment: i want to display all the words in tamil language instead of english in my mfc dialog. But how to display tamil letters in mfc dialog